# kotlin android get deleted value from realm-java

Tags: java, android, kotlin, realm

I use realm-java on Android. now I'm creating profile function, but I'm not sure how to user realm correctly.

when renew profile,
delete value -> store value
but, I fetch value from realm, sometimes old value is taken.

To reproduce,
My test repository is below, and I attached movie that problem is reproduced.
https://github.com/shinsan/realm_test/

When thread id is changed, sometimes old value appears.
so, if you try to reproduce, please use lower memory device such as nexus5 simulator
#I think Realm instance is singleton and transaction is thread-safe, so value is always only one.

my code
kotlin + Android Studio
Realm Java 10.3

//Store

```
val realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
realm.executeTransaction {
val entity = AccountProfileEntity(accountProfile)
it.copyToRealmOrUpdate(entity)
}
```

//Delete

```
val realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
val entity = realm.where(AccountProfileEntity::class.java).findFirst()
realm.executeTransaction {
entity?.deleteFromRealm()
}
```

//Fetch

```
val realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
val instance = realm.where(AccountProfileEntity::class.java).findFirst()
return instance?.toModel()
```

// profile get function

```
override suspend fun getProfile(isForce: Boolean): AccountProfile =
withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
if (isForce) {
database.delete()
}

val profile = database.fetch()
if (profile != null) {
return@withContext profile
}

val token = prefs.getToken() ?: throw NoTokenException
val response = service.getProfile(token)
database.store(response)
response
}
```

Please Help

Comment: I erased the extra code.
Lower Spec AVD is easy to reproduction such as (Nexus4 or 5 RAM 512MB VM heap 40MB)
easy to change process id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this. simply I forgot to close realm instance each fetch, store, delete.